# Application scoped bean in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am learning about bean scopes in Spring and going through this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes#3-application-scope) it says the bean behaves as a singleton across multiple servlet-based applications running in the same `ServletContext`. I am confused about what does servlet context refer to. Does it refer to the container like tomcat because they refer to multiple servlet based applications. As i understand it, it means if i have multiple web apps deployed on a single tomcat instance and i want these apps to refer/share an object then i create an application scoped bean?

Please help if my understanding is correct.

Answer (score -1):

5 Scopes of Spring Bean:

1.Singleton

2.Prototype

These scope will only work for a web application

3.Request
4.Session
5.Application

How to define scope in .xml configuration file:

Singleton bean:

By default ApplicationContext has a singleton scope.This means only one object will be c
created. And if we call  'n' number of getBean() then all the bean will point to the same
bean. Constructor will only be called once.

Prototype:

Will create a new bean each time getBean() is called.
Each bean will have its own hashcode.

@ApplicationScope:

Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a ServletContext.
Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.

Bean Initialization:

When does a 'prototype' scoped bean and a singleton scoped bean gets initialized?

- Singleton scoped beans initialize when the container starts.
- Prototype scoped beans initialize when we ask for it using the getBean() method.
- Prototype bean also gets intialize when it is used as a dependency inside a singleton
  scoped bean.

Comment: this does not answer the question